# Pwinty api for ios

Tags: ios, https, http-post

I have tried a lot but I was unable to use Pwinty api for my ios app. I tried Pwinty sample ios app but it was also not working. Please Help me Pwinty api is not returning the order id which have created with the post method.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? If so, can you provide more details of what you've tried, i.e. your POST request, and whatever Pwinty response that your are getting. If you can provide that, I'll do my best to answer, as I've been muddling through it myself over the last couple of days.

Comment: @JoshHeald Thanks But I have resolved this issue. It was Pwinty issue now Pwinty has updated to version 2.1 and working perfectly for me. I have integrated it in my app you can see its working from the follwoing app simply go to settings -> Pwinty in the app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photify-free-photo-editor/id807184699?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to try an alternative https://www.kite.ly have a dedicated iOS print SDK which might make your life much easier.

- iOS Print SDK: https://github.com/OceanLabs/iOS-Print-SDK

[image: Kite iOS use case]

Full disclosure: I'm cofounder of the company so a little biased, but our products and offerings also happen to be really really good (especially from a developer integration point of view) so I'll take any chance to shout about it ;)

We're all about high quality, beautiful personalised products and we're adding new ones all the time: Photo Prints, Magnets, Postcards, Posters, Stickers, Phone cases, etc, etc...

We also have:

- REST Print API: https://www.kite.ly/docs/1.1/
- Android Print SDK: https://github.com/OceanLabs/Android-Print-SDK

Several of our partners also have millions of users hitting our services so you'll be in good company!